# Piped heredoc precedence in bash

Tags: c, bash, shell, pipe, heredoc

I'm writing my own version of bash in C. Currently, I'm stuck at replicating heredoc behavior when it is piped to another command.
I've referred to bash documentation (https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) but didn't find any info concerning precedence of how piped heredoc is executed.

In bash, the command `cat << hi | echo 123` first scans input as heredoc into `cat`, then redirects everything it accumulated into `echo` (which doesn't read any input), and then `123` is printed.

The current version of my shell, when executing the same command, first writes `123` and simultaneously scans input into `cat` through heredoc.

So bash:

```
bash-3.2$ cat << hi | echo 123
> a
> b
> c
> hi
123
```

My shell:

```
MyShell$ cat << hi | echo 123
> 123
a
> b
> c
> hi
a
b
c
```

My code for pipes:

```
static int  substitution_in(t_ast *node, int fd_redirect[2])
{
    int child_pid;

    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd_redirect[1]);
        dup2(fd_redirect[0], 0);
        close(fd_redirect[0]);
        node->exec(node);
        exit(1);
    }
    return (child_pid);
}

static int  substitution_out(t_ast *node, int fd_redirect[2])
{
    int child_pid;

    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd_redirect[0]);
        dup2(fd_redirect[1], 1);
        close(fd_redirect[1]);
        node->exec(node);
        exit(1);
    }
    return (child_pid);
}

static int  pipe_exec(t_ast *self)
{
    int fd_redirect[2];
    int left_pid;
    int right_pid;

    pipe(fd_redirect);
    right_pid = substitution_out(self->right, fd_redirect);
    left_pid = substitution_in(self->left, fd_redirect);    
    close(fd_redirect[0]);
    close(fd_redirect[1]);
    waitpid(right_pid, NULL, 0);
    waitpid(left_pid, NULL, 0);
    return (0);
}
```

My code for heredoc:

```
static void heredoc(char *delimeter, int env_subst_needed, int *fd_here)
{
    char    *line_read;

    line_read = readline("> ");
    while (strcmp(line_read, delimeter))
    {
        if (env_subst_needed)
            handle_envs(&line_read);
        write(fd_here[1], line_read, strlen(line_read));
        write(fd_here[1], "\n", 1);
        line_read = readline("> ");
    }
}

static int  two_left_redir(t_ast *self)
{
    char    *delimeter;
    int     env_subst_needed;
    int     fd_redirect[2];
    char    *line_read;

    restore_original_file_descriptors();
    delimeter = self->left->data;
    env_subst_needed = !has_quotes(delimeter);
    resect_quotes_from_line(&delimeter);
    pipe(fd_redirect);
    heredoc(delimeter, env_subst_needed, fd_redirect);
    close(fd_redirect[1]);
    dup2(fd_redirect[0], 0);
    close(fd_redirect[0]);
    return (0);
}
```

I read the line, split it into tokens, and build an abstract syntax tree.
Tokens list looks like this:

```
Token value:    cat
Token value:    <<
Token value:    "hi"
Token value:    |
Token value:    echo
Token value:    123
```

The AST looks like this:

```
|Node data: |
|LEFT {
|   |Node data: echo
|   |RIGHT {
|   |   |Node data: 123
|   |}
|}
|RIGHT {
|   |Node data: <<
|   |LEFT {
|   |   |Node data: "hi"
|   |}
|   |RIGHT {
|   |   |Node data: cat
|   |}
|}
```

Why is heredoc the first to scan input? Why does the second command print its output only when the first command (heredoc) meets the delimiter?

Comment: You are starting to evaluate your pipeline before you have read the complete command. `bash` waits until the entire *logical* command (which spans multiple lines) has been read before building the pipe and forking.

Comment: That is, `pipe_exec` should probably be doing both forks, rather than `substitution_in` and `substitution_out` each doing their own (prematurely).

Comment: @chepner
The `substitiution_in` and `substitiution_out` functions run simultaneously because of `forks()` inside them. Also, I first read the whole command, build an AST out of it, and execute the AST.

Comment: Simultaneously, but is `substitution_out` executing `echo` while `substution_in` is still parsing the heredoc? (I mean, it is, because you can see `123` immediately while you are still typing the heredoc. You need to finish parsing the entire heredoc before you execute any part of the pipe.)

Comment: @chepner Answering your question, no. The whole parsing has totally finished before executing anything, including `substitiution_in` and `substitiution_out`. Refer to my edit.

Comment: That's the problem. You *didn't* finish parsing; the entirely here document should be part of the AST for the `cat` command, not just `<<` and `hi`. (Unrelated, your AST seems to be reversed; I would have though `echo` should be in the `RIGHT` node.)

Comment: `echo` is not a great example for a command to pipe to, because it ignores standard input – i.e., your example doesn't make much sense in the first place.